Blaze persistence, entityViewManager.remove transaction is not active
@Override
public void deleteRecords() {
    entityViewManager.remove(entityManager, WatchlistRecordDeletableView.class, 90504L);
}

Trying to remove an Entity via remove() method provided by Blaze Persistence according to documentation (https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#updatable-entity-view-delete-cascading-orphan-removal)
By invoking this method I get error : "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction is not active!"
What may be the problem here?
Tried adding @Transactional annotation to the method but it did not solve the issue
